# How do I add a second dimension/axis to roles in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET application that has requires roles and sites.

Simplified Example:

Site A: Admin, Editor, ReadOnly

Site B: Admin, Editor, ReadOnly

Site C: Admin, Editor, ReadOnly

The built-in ASP.NET roles action filters can handle one dimension of our need, roles, but it doesn't take into account which site the role is from.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Editor")]
public ActionResult EditSiteStatus(int SiteId)
{
  // do work for this site
  // should only be done by Admins or Editors authorized for this site only.
}
```

Is there a way to configure/extend the roles for a second dimension/axis (the site)? Each site will need the same roles as the original site.

An "editor" from Site B should not be able to edit for Site C, unless granted that permission.

(I fear this might end up in the gray area of subjective question limbo, but I believe there is a kernel of knowledge in it that is useful to many if you have suggestions on how to word it better)

Comment: How are you storing the site association in regards to a user?

Comment: I am in design phase, so I am open on how to store them. I am asking this question to determine if I will be able to use the built-in ASP.NET roles. I may need to build a custom User+Role+Site mapping table and some custom Action Filters instead of the built in roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're best off writing your own `AuthorizeAttribute` to do that, something like this:

Usage:

```
[AuthorizeSiteLevel(SiteLevel = "A", Roles = "Admin, Editor")]
public ActionResult EditSiteStatus(int SiteId)
{
    // do work for this site
    // should only be done by Admins or Editors authorized for this site only.
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class AuthorizeSiteLevelAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    protected List<string> Roles { get; private set; }
    protected string SiteLevel { get; private set; }
    protected AuthorizeUserAttribute(string siteLevel, params string[] roles)
    {
        SiteLevel = siteLevel;
        Roles = roles.ToList();
    }

    protected virtual bool Authorize()
    {
        //Authorize logic here, checking User.IsInRole for each of the Roles

        return authorized;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        Controller = (BaseController)filterContext.Controller;

        if (!Authorize())
        {
            filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Good solution. I think you're right about the custom attribute. The only drawback of this implementation for my purpose as it requires the "SiteLevel" to be hard coded, meaning I would need a copy for each site. It would be nice if the "SiteId" was "A" (or actually 1 as it is an int) that the filter required that the "Admin, Editor" roles match the same site #1. I think that can be done. Basically Authorize() would need to ensure that the role matched for the SiteId specified.

Comment: @DanSorensen Ah, that's the drawback yeah. Otherwise you'd have to perform the check yourself on every action that needed it. You could store them in an Enum or something? Then do `Sites.SiteA`or something?